# Count word frequences and then sort them

Tags: regex, perl, count, words, word-frequency

I'm writing a perl script where a should process the text and then provide the dictionary with word frequences and then sort the dictionary. The text is an extract from "Golden Bug" by Edgar Poe and the purpose is to calculate frequences of all of the words. But I do smth wrong because I get no output. When am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
open(TEXT, "goldenbug.txt") or die("File not found");
while(<TEXT>)
{
chomp;
$_=lc;
s/--/ /g;
s/ +/ /g;
s/[.,:;?"()]//g;

@word=split(/ /);
foreach $word (@words)
    {
        if( /(\w+)'\W/ )
        {
            if($1 eq 'bug')
            {
                $word=~s/'//g;
            }
        }
        if( /\W'(\w+)/)
        {
            if(($1 ne 'change') and ($1 ne 'em') and ($1 ne 'prentices'))
            {
                $word=~s/'//g;
            }
        }

        $dictionary{$word}+=1;
    }
}

foreach $word(sort byDescendingValues keys %dictionary)
{
print "$word, $dictionary{$word}\n";
}

sub byDescendingValues
{
$value=$dictionaty{$b} <=> $dictionary{$a};
if ($value==0)
{
return $a cmp $b
}
else
{
    return $value;
}
}
```

Comment: can you post a small word list as well? also you are not declaring %dictionary anywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have in your code:

```
@word=split(/ /);
foreach $word (@words)
    {
```

You've named the array as `@word` during the split but you are using the array `@words` in the for loop.

```
@word=split(/ /);
```

should be

```
@words=split(/ /);
```

Another typo in the `byDescendingValues` routine:

```
$value=$dictionaty{$b} <=> $dictionary{$a};
                ^^
```

As suggested in other answer, you really should add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Using these you could have easily caught these typos. Without them you'll be wasting lot of your time.

Comment: but how to sort the words properly?

Answer (score 2):

As well as confusing @word and @words, you are also using $dictionaty instead of $dictionary. It is wise to

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the start of your program and declare all of your variables using `my`. That way trivial bugs like this are fixed by Perl itself.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the bugs are highlighted, not fixed